Lost $80 and never got anything back
Transaction hash
0x74172b4cbe05721616339a2f53dcb27d68697de736b47f424e1d78e1e65a567f
I want to know why I didn’t get my PEPE I tried to purchase over a year ago using Coinbase wallet. I only clicked trade max amount and started working. Everything was going fine and So I text back later..nothing. Can you see with this hash maybe something I missed. Thanks so much

transaction locked up and not finished


The transaction reverted because it ran out of gas.
In total 0.021467342409539578 ETH was consumed by the transaction. That's where your money went.
